# Outputting batch file to JTextArea

Tags: java, batch-file, jtextarea

I have some code set up that is supposedly running the batch file. I'm not sure though because it's not showing anything in the console, but when I click the JButton PING, the button holds in the click for a couple seconds so it's definitely processing something. What I need help with is outputting the batch file to a JTextArea in my GUI. I'm not really sure how to direct my code to my JTextArea called "textarea". Can someone show me how you would add textarea into this code to get the output? Thanks!

```
JButton btnPingComputer = new JButton("PING");
    btnPingComputer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                   // create a new process
                 // System.out.println("Creating Process...");
                   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\ping.bat");

                   // get the input stream of the process and print it
                   InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
                   for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
                   System.out.println("" + in.read());
                   }
                   for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
                        textArea.append(in.read()+"\n");
                    }
                   // wait for 10 seconds and then destroy the process

                   p.destroy();

                   } catch (Exception ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                   }




        }
    });
```

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/650869/GUI/java/outputting-batch-file-launched-Jbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
    textarea.append(in.read()+"\n");
}
```

EDIT:
I think there could be also a problem with `in.available()`. You can try to change this completly:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\ping.bat");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    textarea.append(line);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: @user6680 You dont get output, so it don't read file or throw exception... maybe it is not processing anything, only `Thread.sleep(10000);` holds it for while. Did you tryed to change value here?

Comment: Nothing happens when I add this code. 
I updated the code above with your mentioned code as well. When I click the button it holds for a couple seconds and then it releases but no data is outputing to the textArea?

Comment: @user6680 but did you tried to remove `Thread.sleep(10000);`? is it make any change?

Comment: The button doesn't freeze now with Thread.sleep(10000); gone now ,but I'm still having the output issue.

Comment: This  outputted to the console like I wanted (almost). I updated my code above. OUTPUT: C:\Users\andrew\workspace\MISCONTROLPANEL>ping 192.168.0.12 and it keeps going.  How can I remove the "C:\Users\andrew\workspace\MISCONTROLPANEL>" Part?

Comment: @user6680 if output is always the same, the easiest way would be to print only a substring of `line` which contains relevant data, for example: `line.substring(line.indexOf("ping"))`, but it is not to elegant solution.

Comment: If I'm pinging a computer with a batch file then the output would most likely not be the same. I'll figure it out. You've been a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code, which will execute the batch file specified and read back anything the batch file echoes back. From there you should be able to take the input and append it to the JTextArea. As long as your bat echoes text back the batOutput should catch it. Watch out for formatting errors due to non-standard characters, however.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String batFile = "C:/test.bat";

      try {
        ProcessBuilder procBuild = new ProcessBuilder(batFile);
        Process proc = procBuild.start();
        InputStream streamIn = proc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(streamIn));
        String batOutput = null;
        while ((batOutput = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(batOutput);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```